# CSV Export PowerShell Script with piped foreach

Tags: powershell, csv, foreach, export-to-csv, citrix

I use the following PowerShell script to get all applications and the users with permission to use them.
Now I want to export the results into CSV, but it doesn't work and I'm clueless why.

```
Add-PSSnapin Citrix*
asnp citrix*
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$OutArray = @()
$OutArray += Get-BrokerApplication -AdminAddress *CITRIX DDC* | ForEach {
    $name        = $_.ApplicationName
    $description = $_.Description
    $assocgroups = $_.AssociatedUserNames

    foreach ($group in $assocgroups) {
        $result = $group -match '^*DOMAIN NAME*\\(.+)$'

        if ($result) {
            $groupname = $Matches[1]
            $members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "$groupname" -Recursive | Select Name,sAMAccountName,distinguishedName,mail

            foreach ($member in $members) {            
                $result = $member.distinguishedname -match 'CN=.+,OU=Users,OU=(.+),OU=Department,DC=*DOMAIN NAME*,DC=de'
                if (-not $result) {
                    # several exceptions from the default user DN exist for administrative users and/or service accounts
                    $result = $member.distinguishedname -match "CN=.+,(?:OU=Administrators,)?OU=(?:Administrators),OU=Infrastructure,DC=*DOMAIN NAME*,DC=de"
                    if (-not $result) {
                        $result = $member.distinguishedname -match "CN=.+,(?:OU=Testusers,)?OU=(?:Service Accounts),?OU=(?:Windows-Servers),OU=Infrastructure,DC=*DOMAIN NAME*,DC=de"
                    }
                }

                if ($result) {
                    $dept = $Matches[1]
                    Write-Host $member.Name";" $groupname";" $group";" $dept
                } else {
                    throw "ERROR: User DN $($member.distinguishedName) does not match any known user departmental OU."
                }
            }
        } else {
            throw "Associated user names field does not match group standard naming scheme."
        }
    } 
} 
$OutArray | Export-Csv C:\temp\test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
An MCVE should include a variety of sample input (illustrating all aspects) and desired output.  
If you are looking for help with debugging code see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/  
Please provide more information on how it does not work, error messages, observed undesired behvaiour, differences to desired output, ...

Comment: Could you show us an example of what you want in the CSV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [`ForEach-Object`](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/07/08/getting-to-know-foreach-and-foreach-object/) loop doesn't produce non-captured output on the [Success output stream](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/). Thus nothing is appended to `$OutArray`, and consequentially, nothing is written to the output CSV.

The output you create via

```
Write-Host $member.Name";" $groupname";" $group";" $dept
```

is written to the host console and cannot be captured. You'd need to replace it with `Write-Output` to get the output written to the Succes output stream (so it can be captured in a variable or processed with a pipeline):

```
Write-Output $member.Name";" $groupname";" $group";" $dept
```

You could also drop the cmdlet entirely, because writing to the output stream is PowerShell's default behavior, but only for single strings, so you'd need to [concatenante](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arithmetic_operators) the elements:

```
$member.Name + ";" + $groupname + ";" + $group + ";" + $dept
```

However, that would still not produce the desired CSV output, because `Export-Csv` expects object input and writes the properties of the objects as the fields of the CSV. If feed it an array of semicolon-separated strings, `Export-Csv` will export the sole property of those string objects (`Length`).

You can either write the list of semicolon-separated strings to an output file with cmdlets like `Out-File` or `Set-Content` (which I wouldn't recommend):

```
$OutArray | Set-Content 'C:\temp\test.csv'
```

or (better) you can construct proper objects inside your loop:

```
New-Object -Type PSObject -Property ([ordered]@{
  Name       = $member.Name
  Groupname  = $groupname
  Group      = $group
  Department = $dept
})
```

and export those objects with `Export-Csv`:

```
$OutArray | Export-Csv 'C:\temp\test.csv' -Delimiter ';' -NoType
```

Also, since both `ForEach-Object` and `Export-Csv` work with the pipeline, you can connect them directly without collecting the output in a variable first:

```
Get-BrokerApplication -AdminAddress *CITRIX DDC* | ForEach-Object {
  ...
} | Export-Csv 'C:\temp\test.csv' -Delimiter ';' -NoType
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try your suggestions and respond as soon as I implemented them :-)

Comment: I have tried your recommendation with proper objects inside my loop and now it works as aspected with the Export-csv 'C:\temp\test.csv' -Delimiter ';' -NoType - another big thanks for your examples and the explanation!